# Passing variables within the application ASP C# Hidden fields

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a variable that I need to use in different parts of my application. I am wondering what would be the best way to store the variable, change it and then access it when needed.

Is it a bad idea to store that in a hidden field? 
Would creating a page level variable for the application in code behind file be a better option?

Some context of what I need. The App starts with giving user an option to either create a topic or open one from a dropdown. Once opened, the users should be a able to add items (stored in database), remove items, add comments etc. to this topic.

My issue is getting the topic_id from code behind (where it is generated) to the front end, so that on a button click I know which topic is active.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with hidden fields, it conforms to the stateless intent of the web.

Comment: Why don't you store it in Session each time this user log in (just visit your site) and use it always ?

Comment: @Crowcoder is the use of hidden fields not a security vulnerability?

Comment: It is no less secure than any form field, unless you mean from the user perspective and you are trying to hide something. But you can't hide anything from a technically savvy user.

Comment: True that sounds good. I think session is probably the best option in this case as I won't have to keep reading and writing the updates to the ID to the client end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Values in hidden fields can be changed by users, I would use instead a session variable, accessible from every controller.

```
var topicId = Session("TopicId");
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/87069683(v=vs.85).aspx